# Fill listview from SQL Server data

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have problem with creating listview I have tried different methods of filling ListView items from SQL Server and I can not solve it.
I created this function to fill the listview dynamically, the connection works so far, so thats not the problem. But currently my problem is, the function creates the row but they remain Empty while the header list work correctly.

I am writing the following code

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="LV" Height="494" Margin="10,30,10,10">
       <ListView.View>
             <GridView>
                  <GridViewColumn/>
             </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

C#

```
            SqlDataAdapter sqladp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, strCon);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sqladp.Fill(ds, dValue);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

            // Add columns
            var gridView = new GridView();
            LV.View = gridView;
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = dt.Columns[i].ToString(),
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding($"[{i}]")
         });
            }

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                //Add Row
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string[] arr = new string[dt.Columns.Count];
                    ListViewItem itm;
                    try
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                            arr[i] = row[i].ToString();

                        LV.Items.Add(arr);

                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            LV.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: You need to define column mapping for more detail please visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-overview

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `rowItems` to `Content`, but `rowItems` is empty and remains empty. Perhaps you meant to assign `Content` to `arr`, which you fill up but then do nothing with it.

Also, you don't need to create the `ListViewItem`s yourself. They're created for you when you add items to the `ListView.Items` property. Change that part of the code to the following (based on your updated code):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    arr[i] = row[i].ToString();

LV.Items.Add(arr);
```

Finally, because you're adding an array (rather than an object with properties), you need to fix the column's binding to the following:

```
gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
{
    Header = dt.Columns[i].ToString(),
    DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding($"[{i}]")
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, you're right. I have change the code but the mistake rimain..I wrote the correct code above

Comment: @BovioS Instead of correcting your code as an answer, you should edit your question with an update containing the corrected code. Also, if you find an answer to be helpful (even if it doesn't answer your question), you should click on the "up" arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thank's thank's thank's now it works, I corrected the code above. Now, I have a a basic question....How can I read the string of the selected row?
I can not use LV.selectedItems[0].subitems[1].Text :(

Comment: @BovioS I wasn't very clear, but what I meant was to add an update to the bottom of your question, not correct your question. Because your code is correct, it will not make sense to any future person wanting to know what the problem was. Please change your code to the original code. Also, you shouldn't ask more questions in the comments. Either add to your current question, or create an entirely new question. Finally, if my answer solved your original problem, please accept it.